# change font size and align navbar-brand

Tags: css, navbar

I have a navbar that works fine but I would like the navbar brand to have a different style font and size and be vertically centered but it seems to change its position when I view it on different browsers and media types and never be in the middle, ie on a iphone, and tablet.

The css code is :

```
 a[href^=tel] { color: inherit; text-decoration: none; }
 .navbar-default {   
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #00a3fe;
    font-size: 14pt;font-weight: 400;}

a:hover {
   text-decoration:none;
}   


.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #49bdfe;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-toggle, .icon-bar {
    border:1px solid white;
    background-color:white;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  color: : white;
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 22px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.navbar-toggle .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}
.navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
     transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.btn-lg {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #49bdfe;
  border-color: #357ebd;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3276b1;
  border-color: #285e8e;
}
```

and the html is :

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
<div class='container'>
<div class='navbar-header'>
<button type='button' class = 'navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle = 'collapse' data-target = '#example-navbar-collapse'>
<span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
<span class='icon-bar top-bar'></span>
<span class='icon-bar middle-bar'></span>
<span class='icon-bar bottom-bar'></span></button>
<span class='navbar-brand'>My Site</span>
   </div>
<div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id = 'example-navbar-collapse'>
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
<li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Get bids</a></li>
<li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Register company</a></li>
<li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: flex; align-items: center` to keep it vertically aligned.

```css
a[href^=tel] { color: inherit; text-decoration: none; }
 .navbar-default {   
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #00a3fe;
    font-size: 14pt;font-weight: 400;}

a:hover {
   text-decoration:none;
}   


.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-nav li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #49bdfe;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-toggle, .icon-bar {
    border:1px solid white;
    background-color:white;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  color: : white;
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 22px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.navbar-toggle .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}
.navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
     transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.btn-lg {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #49bdfe;
  border-color: #357ebd;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3276b1;
  border-color: #285e8e;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font: 24px cursive!important;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
<div class='container'>
<div class='navbar-header'>
<button type='button' class = 'navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle = 'collapse' data-target = '#example-navbar-collapse'>
<span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
<span class='icon-bar top-bar'></span>
<span class='icon-bar middle-bar'></span>
<span class='icon-bar bottom-bar'></span></button>
<span class='navbar-brand'>My Site</span>
   </div>
<div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id = 'example-navbar-collapse'>
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
<li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Get bids</a></li>
<li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Register company</a></li>
<li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'>Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
        <li><a href='about.php' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp' role='button'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: cool man thanks, if I want the actual background bigger in length, how do i do that? If i change it my way, everything stays at the top and the buttons are half the lengh!

Comment: @Jules what background? And what's "my way"?